# How to enforce custom MySQL column format

Tags: mysql, regex

What if I wanted to define a custom column format in MySQL?  The custom format that I want is always a 2 digit integer, followed by the # sign, then a space, then a decimal number with 2 digits after the decimal.  Examples of allowed values are like this:

```
30# 11.00
27# 17.25
40# 17.25
```

values that are **not allowed** are like this:

```
30# 11
40# 20.5
some string
```

Is this possible in MySQL?  If so, any hints on how to do it?

Comment: Well, you can always do it in an easy approach and that is a relation to the table that would have `id int float(4,2)` :)

Comment: now i use varchar, of course, but i want to enforce this custom format.  If you try to insert a value that is not in this desired format, the database should return an error and not let you save it.

Comment: I think that @AndriusNaruševičius is correct. Every value in database table should be atomic, because of searching, sorting and other operations. You can set constraints on individual colums easier than on one composite column.

Comment: Right I agree.  I would never design a database in this way.  Unfortunately I have had the pleasure of converting older database programs into web-based apps.  I am trying to see what kind of knowledge is out there.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well since "The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines." in mysql, your only remaining option would be to add a before insert/update trigger on your table to [regexp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) your input and proceed.

Comment: Yes i was hoping to not have to do a trigger, but i think you are probably right it is the only way to do it.

Comment: yes triggers should only be used only at the most desperate moment. Maybe it would be acceptable for your application to enforce these checks at the applicative layer?

Comment: Currently, a trigger is the only way to enforce this in MySQL.