# MySQL update syntax to convert column to custom format

Tags: mysql, regex, custom-formatting

This question is related to another question, where I wanted to define a custom MySQL column format.  The question is here: [How to enforce custom MySQL column format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103391/how-to-enforce-custom-mysql-column-format).

The custom format that I want is always a 2 digit integer, followed by the # sign, then a space, then a decimal number with 2 digits after the decimal. Examples of allowed values are like this:

```
30# 11.00
27# 17.25
40# 17.25
```

values that are not allowed are like this:

```
30# 11
40# 20.5
27# 13
```

As you can see, the problem with the values that aren't allowed is basically just the last decimal number is missing the "." and trailing zeros.  Is there some update syntax that I can use to fix all these *incorrect* column values?  Basically I just need to check if the last decimal number after the "# " have the 2 trailing decimal digits.  If it doesn't then I want to add the "." and the trailing zeros.  Does anyone know an `UPDATE` command that can do this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

answers to some of the comments:  Yes it is `VARCHAR` type column.  If the value is completely different than what we want, then just leave it alone.  Most of the problems are what I explained, and if i can fix all of those with one query then that is a good start.

Comment: There probably is a way to do it in MySQL, but I'd suggest doing data manipulation in your programming language of choice, not the store it self.

Comment: 1- what is the column type? varchar? 2-what kind of input could you get? What if there's a totally unrelated string incoming (by mistake), raise an error?

Comment: According to Qtax, you shouldn't manipulate your datas with MySQL, the only way to do it will be a trigger, but use PHP (?) to do it, you'll have whatever you want/need.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Yes I realize i can do all this in PHP or Python.  Recently I have been trying to do as much inside the MySQL framework as possilbe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update your_table
set some_column = case when len(some_column) = 6
                       then some_column + '.00'
                       when len(some_column) = 8
                       then some_column + '0'
                  end
where len(some_column) < 9;
```

See [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5faaa/3)

here is some more precise syntax that worked very well:

```
update your_table 
set some_column =
case 
    when length(some_column) = 6 
    then concat(some_column,".00") 
    when length(some_column) = 7
    then concat(some_column,"00") 
    when length(some_column) = 8
    then concat(some_column,"0") 
    else some_column 
end 
where some_column REGEXP '^[0-9][0-9]# [0-9][0-9]';
```

Comment: And if you try `abcdefghi` ? You still need to treat your datas in amont.

Comment: C@@L, first time I see SQL Fiddle!